# Redeem Command (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

Hello my name is jake I'm looking for help on creating a redemption command in discord.js, Baseline idea.

!redeem XXX-XXX-XXXX
If it's a valid code then it runs a line of code bla bla, (Enables the bot premium features for that server and makes the code invalid).

I was think in using a generator and generating a few thousand codes and storing it in a .env file, so how would I exactly code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach is to generate codes and save them in a database table. So if a user tries to redeem a code, you can query the database and see if it exists.

For database I recommend [sqlite3](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/) since it's lightweight.

For generating codes there is a good [library](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/) you can use.

For example,

```
db.run('CREATE TABLE promo_codes(code text)');

// generating and saving a promo code
const addCode = () => {
  const code = voucher_codes.generate({
    pattern: "###-###-####",
  });
  db.run("INSERT INTO promo_codes(code) VALUES (?)",code, function(err){
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err.message);
    }
  });
}

// generating 1000
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  addCode()
}
```

Comment: How would I check the if its a valid code in a comamnd? Sorry I'm new to scripting discord bots.

Comment: You might want to learn more about SQL databases first if you haven't worked with one before. But you can try validating a code by querying it in the database. For example, if a user tries to redeem code `123-456-7890`, you can run `db.get("SELECT * FROM promo_codes where code=?", "123-456-7890", errorHandler)`. In the `errorHandler`, if there is an error,  then the code is invalid, otherwise it is valid. See more about querying [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/). If you want to invalidate the code after redemption, you can delete it from the table.

Comment: I kind of came up with a kind of complicated proccess I think using my site.

Heres my example url:
Is this ridiculous for my bot premium code redemption url? https://example.com/rohelper/redeem/redeem.php?code=abcGGag3jwNwaufwggw%guild=715752721818320978%user=295744013406044162

Just about done, but you were a big help.

Comment: I think that url is fine